# In API16, Android App can't launch with emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, cocos2d-x

**Environment**
Cocos2d-x 3.15
Android Studio 2.3.1

**build.gradle**

```
compileSdkVersion 16
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
minSdkVersion 10
targetSdkVersion PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION(Set to 13 in gradle.properties)
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

I added the following.

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="13" android:minSdkVersion="13"></uses-sdk>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"></uses-feature>
```

**Problem**
I run the command `cocos run -p android --android-studio -ap android-16` 
and it succeeded.
But when I run my app with AVD Nexus S API 16, the app was down.
However, this problem didn't occur in API 25.
There are some error messages in the Debug console and logcat.

```
Signal: SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x592e5dd8))
3963-3963/? E/Trace: error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
 E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API*
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: what is your minimum sdk version ?

Comment: minSdkVersion is 10.

Comment: Did you enable OpenGL in the emulator? (It's the "Use Host GPU" check button) , may be not getting an OpenGL context from the emulator. Why don't you try on real devices

Comment: I did set both Automatic, Hardware GLES 2.0, Software GLES 1.1 with AVD and run it. but All app launching failed. I haven't run on My device, but I want to support old android devices like API 15, 16...